# Exception occurs while deserialize json containing date with different format C#

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json-deserialization

Having json string containing date field

```
{
  "totalSize": 2,
  "records": [
    {
      "Id": "5006C000008ZhEDQA0",
      "CreatedDate": "2021-12-01T15:14:20.000+0000",
      "CaseNumber": "01378682",
      "Status": "Open"
    },
    {
      "Id": "5006C000008ZhE00A0",
      "CreatedDate": "2021-12-05T08:00:00.000+0000",
      "CaseNumber": "01378692",
      "Status": "Open"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to do normal Deserialization where **CreatedDate** datatype is DateTime.

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SFHistoryResponse>(stringResponse);
```

I'm getting

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime. Path:
> $.records[0].CreatedDate

is there any way to format JSON's date part before Deserialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Newtonsoft JSON library can deserialize the string properly without throwing an exception:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var response =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SFHistoryResponse>(stringResponse);
```

Comment: same thing i did.. and its throwing error as date format in json is "2021-12-05T08:00:00.000+0000" and it wont work

Comment: i did trick by replacing ".000+0000" with "" before deserialization but its marked as in appropriate

Comment: You're using the deserializer out of System.Text.Json. It isn't the same.

Comment: ohh my bad, i will try this right away

Answer (score 1):

In your case your classes need to be:

```
  public class Record
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class SFHistoryResponse
{
    public int totalSize { get; set; }
    public List<Record> records { get; set; }
}
```

and when you try to deserialize the json

```
SFHistoryResponse l = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SFHistoryResponse>(jsonString);
```

tested my self

```
tbResult.Text = "l.records[0].CreatedDate.ToString() - " + l.records[0].CreatedDate.ToString();
```

[image]